# serve js files from meteor app to other server

Tags: javascript, meteor

I trying to make a service like google analytics, where the user put a script in their html.

the problem is when my sever serve the script it have to make some operations and send different script depending from the requesting domain.

sorry for my english

and thanks so much for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I, found the solution, really easy

in server folder:

```
Router.route("metric", {
    where: "server",
    path: "/dinamic.js",
    action: function () {
        //here all your acctions
        ponse.writeHead(200, {
            "Content-Type": "application/javascript"
        });
        this.response.end(
            "console.log('in this line your dynamic " + "js" + " code')"
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

**You can produce JS dynamically from PHP**

**Plz take reference from this example**

**script.php**

```
<?php
$id=$_REQUEST["id"];
$name=$_REQUEST["name"];
if($id>10)
?>
 console.log("Hello <?php echo $name;?> your ID is <?php echo $id;?>");
<?php
else 
?>
 alert("Hello <?php echo $name;?> your ID is <?php echo $id;?>");
```

**In your html code (under a server side script file) you just need to dynamically change the src attrbute of the script tag**

```
<script src="script.php?name=<?php echo $your_name;?>&id=<?php echo $your_id;?>"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking serve from  nodejs.

Comment: You can also do the same thing in node js. The template which you want to render should have similar code with the node js structure